# CakePHP session should not started on certain controller actions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am using session handling using Database. For some webservice calls using RequestHandler I want to stop auto session create for these some certain action of controller

My question:
How can I stop auto session start in some actions of the controller? Please note that I defined Auth component in AppController.
Is there any way stop session in action? Do I need to use $this->Session->destroy() in action?

### Clarification

On each webservice call It creates a new session row in database. but I don't use any session feature in action.i.e. If anybody call 10 times a action it creates 10 sessions. I feel it will create database space and time overhead.

### Apply New changes as suggested

Could not get proper result by using this

```
 // overwrite constructClasses() for remove session in certain actions
     public function constructClasses() {
         // remove the Session from components again here
         // either globally or for certain actions

         if (in_array($this->action,  array('test1','test2'))) {
            foreach($this->components as $key => $val){
                if($val =='Session'){
                   unset($this->components[$key]);
                }
            }    
         }
         parent::constructClasses();
     }
```

But still new session Id created on test1 0r test2 by API Call

```
// out put of below code.
function beforeFilter() {
    pr($this->components);     
}
```

```
Array
(
    [Cookie] => 
    [Auth] => Array
        (
            [loginAction] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => resources
                    [action] => login
                )
```

```
        [loginRedirect] => Array
            (
                [controller] => resources
                [action] => view
            )

        [logoutRedirect] => Array
            (
                [controller] => resources
                [action] => login
            )

        [authenticate] => Array
            (
                ......

            )

    )

[Security] => Array
    (
        [csrfExpires] => +1 hour
    )

[RequestHandler] =>
```

)

Comment: "Do I need to use $this->Session->destroy() in action" => session not starting is not the same as destroying sessions.. What is your exact Cake Version? it cannot be 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 3):

The key is to not access the session in those actions.
As long as you don't access it the session will not start itself.

So either try `$this->Auth->allow()` for those to prevent cake to check your Auth session, or remove the Auth component alltogether from this controller:

```
// overwrite constructClasses()
public function constructClasses() {
     // remove the Auth/Session from components again here
     // either globally or for certain actions
     if (in_array($this->action, $myListOfActions)) {
         // ...
     }
     parent::constructClasses();
}
```

Also make sure you don't read the session from your AppController callbacks (beforeFilter/render etc).

Either way, make sure nothing tries to look into the session.
Also note, that there have been some recent improvements to prevent unnecessary session lookups in 2.3 regarding Auth AFAIK. You might want to try that if the above fails.

I would also advice you to separate your controller actions into real API ones and non-api ones. Don't mix those two!
This avoids the action based separation you seem to be needing.
Just have a webservice controller (session free) and a backend controller (user/session) etc. They can still share/use the same model.

Comment: I used $this->Auth->allow() in beforeFilter of the controller

Comment: Can you remove the Auth component and all Session access? Does this work?

Comment: Yes! You are right. I used $this->Auth->loggedIn() and $this->Cookie->read('remember_me_cookie')) in beforeFilter function of AppController

Comment: I am using cakephp version 2.3.5

Comment: I removed session in $components array but can not remove Auth component as Auth is being used in before filter of App Controller

Comment: You can hard-remove it for now for testing - also put a "throw CakeException" in your CakeSession class (read etc) to see what else is accessing the session now in those actions.

Comment: On removing session from $components array. Script does not create new session in API specific Actions. Now other problem occurred, Other actions show error when using $this->Session->write or $this->Session->read in it.

Comment: You need to remove it ONLY from that controller - and maybe even only for specific actions then.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I remove sessionComponent for certain actions?

Comment: Note that there is also the 2.4 `$this->Auth->sessionKey = false;` now.

Comment: Thanks for telling this.. But this solution also not working. I tried this->Session->destroy();   + delete current session Id from DB in beforeFilter. but don't know why it creates new sessionId on every request

Comment: As I mentioned from the very beginning you should leave the session alone if you dont want it to be triggered. So using "this->Session->destroy(); + delete current session Id from DB" seesm to be like the worst thing one can do if you dont want the session to be started.. Way more helpful would be to find out where CakeSession::start() is being called and try to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Yes I am agree with you. But after doing all your suggestions and googled I could not found any solution to do this.